# How to integrate SageMaker Clarify Explainability and HPO in AWS Sagemaker?

Tags: python, aws-sdk, amazon-sagemaker-studio, amazon-sagemaker-clarify, amazon-sagemaker-experiments

I'm wondering to use Sagemaker clarify explainability in combination with HPO. I saw the sagemaker examples using the 'experiments.run ([docs link][1]), but I did not figure out how to adapt for HPO task. Thank you all for any help.

Short docs examples using xgboost:

```
with Run(
    experiment_name=experiment_name,
    run_name="combined-report",
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
) as run:  # model training and explainability reports created in the same experiment run
    xgb.fit({"train": train_input}, logs=False)
   
    clarify_processor.run_explainability(
        data_config=explainability_data_config,
        model_config=model_config,
        explainability_config=shap_config,
    )
```

Instead, I would like to use the HPO:

```
clarify.run_exaplainability(params) # combine it with HPO bellow

optimizer = sagemaker.tuner.HyperparameterTuner(
                            container,
                            hyperparameter_ranges=hp_ranges,
                            stratefy='Random',
                            objecive_type='Maximize',
                            objective_metric_name='val:auc',
                            metric_definitons=metric_definitions,
                            max_jobs=10,
                            max_parallel_jobs=2,
)
optimizer.fit(data_channels, wait=True)
``


  [1]: https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker-experiments/sagemaker_clarify_integration/tracking_bias_explainability.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in the docs the `experiment_config` parameter of `run_explainability`. It allowed me to include the explainability result in the main HPO job. So, I ran HPO and then I get the last job to include in `run_explainability`. In short:

```
clarify.run_explainability(
   ...,
   ...,
   experiment_config={'ExperimentName': optimizer.latest_jtuning_job.name}
)
```

Note: It includes the explainability in the main job and not for each hpo training.